# Using iframe tag in react application with local html file

Tags: reactjs, iframe

What is the best way to use `iframe` in react application, while having local html file for `ifram src`.

I need to have an `iframe` in my react application, but the `iframe` does not work with my local html file.

```js
function ClusterDetails() {

  return (
    <iframe title='mytitle' src="../../data/index.html" width='500px'  height='500px'></iframe>
  );
}

export default ClusterDetails;
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. The source of iframe should be placed in **public** folder. the `src` attribute of iframe should be addressed related to public folder.

For example if there is a **data** folder containing **index.html** file, in public folder, then the `src` should be set as `'data/index.html'`

Comment: I get a "Cannot GET" in the iframe when trying this